# What are the User Groups assigned to administrator accounts in Windows Vista Home Basic?

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts

Windows Vista Home Basic does not have the **local groups** pane. How how can I tell what groups my user account is a member of?

I need to know so I can build an unattended installation, what group(s) should my first Admin user belong to?

Comment: This question falls outside the scope of serverfault.com topics, as explained in the [faq](http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: [Unattended install of Home Basic?](http://i.imgur.com/DUmXd.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net user username` should show group membership of a user account.

`net localgroup` should show what local groups exist on the machine.

There is a local group named `Administrators` on every Windows installation. If you want to make someone an administrator, add them to that.